# How to CAST an Alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate a due amount summing and grouping more amounts in table i_payment_history comparing then the result with the total "to_be_payed" amount saved in table pt_bookings. All involved fields are decimal(8,2), i have tryied with Cast becouse without is not working eather. The value "Due" is just the result of 'to_be_payed'-'payed'
so the first value in column "Due" should be 755,10-200,00=535,10 .
Why is "Due" calculating a wrong value? Txs !

```
SELECT i_payments_history.booking_id, Cast(SUM(amount)AS DECIMAL(8,2)) as  payed, pt_bookings.booking_total, pt_bookings.booking_ref_no, (pt_bookings.booking_total - payed) as due
FROM `i_payments_history`
JOIN pt_bookings
on pt_bookings.booking_id= i_payments_history.booking_id    
GROUP BY booking_id
```

see in below pic what the query is returning

[image]

Comment: `pay` is an irregular verb, so `pay`-->`paid`, not `payed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeat the expression:

```
SELECT ph.booking_id, Cast(SUM(ph.amount) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) as  payed, b.booking_total, b.booking_ref_no,
       (b.booking_total - SUM(ph.amount)) as due
FROM `i_payments_history` ph JOIN
     pt_bookings b
     on b.booking_id = ph.booking_id    
GROUP BY b.booking_id;
```

An alias cannot be used in the same `select` where it is defined.  One alternative is to use a subquery; another is to repeat the expression.  Your query did not return an error because one of your tables must have a column named `payed`.